# SQL Syntax error in writing a query

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

Right, here is my code. I get the error;

"Script line: 4 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT *
FROM UserAvailabilities
WHERE user_id = '0'

END' at line 4
"
This is one of my first queries, and i dont know where i am going wrong. Its a bit nooby, but can someone point it out to me?

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `getUserAvailabilityStation` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`web`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getUserAvailabilityStation`(_user_id int(11))
BEGIN

SELECT *
FROM UserAvailabilities
WHERE user_id = '0'

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

EDIT: Solved the problem, the "WHERE user_id = 0" needed a semi colon at the end. Nooby mistakes FTL. Thanks for the help thought guys

Comment: What RDBMS is this? (Always good to include when asking an SQL question) `"` (not `\``) are SQL-92 identifier quotes, but this varies widely between implementations... in any case, I avoid using identifier quotes unless required. It is just icky to read ;-)

Comment: Where are you selecting the data to? Your current `select` query is just pointless

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes and add an underscore:

```
SELECT *
FROM UserAvailabilities
WHERE user_id = 0;
```

Comment: @McAzzaMan fixing my answer. try again.

Comment: Needed a semi colon on the end :/ Can you edit your answer to include this? So i can flag it as correct for anyone else who needs it?

Comment: Definitely not: _user_id is the parameter. user_id is the column name. It's a common pattern to namespace params with leading underscore